# How to check if phone number is valid in android

Tags: java, android

On my application's signup page I have an OTP checking.

My problem is I want to validate the phone number before sending OTP.

How to can I create a phone number validation regex according to the extension(for Oman +968, for Canada +1)

I have tried PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber(phoneNumber); api for validating phone number. But the api always returns true.

For example, I have passed "0" to the API, but it returns true.

Is there any better option to validate the phone number with the country extension code?

Comment: use `PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);`

Comment: i suggest you show some research effort and what you have tried to achieve what you are asking

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Comment: @Shinil  I have already tried PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber() function. But if i pass any number like "0" the api returns true. It is not correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)** is not a proper way to check phone number is valid or not. I found a better solution for this and it is working for me.

First we need to add below library in the gradle file.

**Library: [com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.4.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.4.2)**

We need to pass mobile number and country code to the below function and it will return true if the phone number is valid.

```
public static PhoneValidateResponse isPhoneNumberValidate(String mobNumber, String countryCode) {
 PhoneValidateResponse phoneNumberValidate = new PhoneValidateResponse();
        PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = null;
        boolean finalNumber = false;
        PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType isMobile = null;
        boolean isValid = false;
        try {
            String isoCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(Integer.parseInt(countryCode));
            phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(mobNumber, isoCode);
            isValid = phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber);
            isMobile = phoneNumberUtil.getNumberType(phoneNumber);
            phoneNumberValidate.setCode(String.valueOf(phoneNumber.getCountryCode()));
            phoneNumberValidate.setPhone(String.valueOf(phoneNumber.getNationalNumber()));
            phoneNumberValidate.setValid(false);

        } catch (NumberParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (isValid && (PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.MOBILE == isMobile ||
                PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberType.FIXED_LINE_OR_MOBILE == isMobile)) {
            finalNumber = true;
            phoneNumberValidate.setValid(true);
        }

        return phoneNumberValidate;
    }
```

Model class PhoneValidateResponse.

```
public class PhoneValidateResponse {
    private String Phone;
    private String Code;
    private boolean isValid;


    public String getPhone() {
        return Phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return Code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        Code = code;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        isValid = valid;
    }
}
```

As per my code if isValid() of PhoneValidateResponse method returns true then the given phone number and country code are matched.

Comment: There is no import option for PhoneNumberUtil in my project. Is there any library issue or something else. Looking forward to your response.